# UICollectionView within UITableView. How to tell tableview cell to change height when collection view gets taller?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uicollectionview

I have a `UITableView` and one of my table cells is a `UICollectionViewController` subclass that contains a `UICollectionView` of displayed email addresses. When a user adds an email the `UICollectionView` and it’s cell in the table view should get taller.

I’m currently attempting to do this setting my `collectionView` height constraint to `collectionView.contentSize.height` in the `LayoutSubviews` method of my collection controller/cell class.  My issue is that the cell in the `UITableView` is not changing size when this happens.

I am assuming that this is because there is nothing telling the table view that the height of the email entry cell has changed. I am currently using dynamic cell sizing - or trying to anyway. Even, if I call `tableView.reloadData()` this still does not work. I’m wondering if  someone could give me a high-level idea of how they would set this up.

UPDATE:

I had a broken constraint issue that was part of my problem, but this is still not solved. While have proven that I can update the height constraint and that will update the size of the collection view, it's out of sync. It's always one update behind. Here's an image showing the 'UICollectionView' in green and you can see in the logs that I'm updating the constraint (yes, multiple times) each time after adding a new item to the collection, but it is not updating the bounds of the view instance. In this example, if I were to add a new item to the collection, the next time I inspect bounds.height it would be at 149.5. What am I missing!?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i had answered this question in another tableview inside tableview cell that will work for collection view too ,i explained it [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43520073/1598912)

ask me if you faced any problem

Answer (score -2):

It seems you want to set the height of your table view cell dynamically. This detailed tutorial walks you through making a custom cell class that will have dynamic height. Unfortunately, this tutorial only walks you through how to do this with auto layout constraints and a storyboard. In the tutorial you'll notice that the height of the cell depends on the constraints put on a title label within the cell. Try doing the same thing, but applying the constraints on the content in your cell (the collection view cell). 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout