# vertical scrolling Collection View Inside Table View cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableView and a segment Control setup on that view. Now when the segment's value changes I want to remove the existing tableView cells and display full collectionView in one of tableView cells.

I have already gone through https://github.com/ashfurrow/Collection-View-in-a-Table-View-Cell and though found it very useful, haven't found the right solution.

Also the collectionView I want to had is vertical scrollable with not fixed height

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this.... share if you did it

Answer (score 0):

i had answered this question in another tableview inside tableview cell that will work for collection view too ,i explained it [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43520073/1598912)

ask me if you faced any problem

Answer (score -1):

```
extension TableViewCell {

func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate<D: protocol<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>>(dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row: Int) {

    collectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
    collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
    collectionView.tag = row
    collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionView.setContentOffset(collectionView.contentOffset, animated:false) // Stops collection view if it was scrolling.
    collectionView.reloadData()
}

var collectionViewOffset: CGFloat {
    set {
        collectionView.contentOffset.x = newValue
    }

    get {
        return collectionView.contentOffset.x
    }


   }
}
```

Comment: I am not able to setup the collectionView inside the tableView yet

Comment: I have the collection view completely setup in a different View Controller, can I just show the view Controller in a tableView cell?

Comment: I think yes. Maybe putting in your storyboard your VC in your dynamic cell.

Comment: Hey, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I have thought but I didn't find any solution.  Try to look some video of "Lets build that app" when he talks about firebase. It is very interesting and he helps you to build a vertical collection view

Comment: There you can try to put that in your tablet view

Comment: I already have a vertical collection view. But how do you suggest it be put in tableview cell?

Comment: Take your collection view code and put into your customized table view cell. Then in your table view call the collection view. With for example cell.collectionView