# Dynamic Height for Multiple UitableView in one view controller

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am looking for a logic to be implemented.

I have Four `UITableView` in One View controller. I want to set the height of every `UITableView` as per the rows present in the `UITableViewCell`. The cell height should be dynamic and `UITableView` also should be dynamic. the `UITableViewCell` has Custom cell which is for all the `tableView`. It has one imageView, 3 labels.

For eg: for 1st tableView it has only one row then the tableView height should be the same as table view cell and if 2nd tableView has 4 rows so the tableView height should be equal to the count of `UITableViewCell` row height.

I have searched a lot before asking this question but I am not able to do it.

Can someone please help me out with the logic as what it can be done.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268463/set-uitableviews-height-to-the-height-of-its-content-with-auto-layout/33268512

Comment: Thank you .. but I did not understand the method updateViewConstraints which has been used @NightFury