# How to increase table view height inside table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i have table view inside table view cell, need to set table view height depending on table view content, i tried below code

```
extension tableViewCell: UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) { [self] in
            lcOptionsTVHeight.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
        }
    }
}
```

but this is not working in first load, but updating as i do scroll up and down, how can do load in properly in first load itself?

Comment: i got it working from anwser - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43520073/9166279

Answer (score 0):

> [heightForRowAt(:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview)

You need to pass your height in heightForRowAt(:)

In this method, you need to check if it's the nested tableview cell and return the height, in other cases just return `UITableView.automaticDimension`

My suggestion would be to use sections instead of nested tableview. Only if there's horizontal scrolling requirement(not the case here as you mentioned tableview inside a tableview cell), we can go with a collectionview inside tableview cell.

Here, using different sections might be sufficient. You can reload sections by `tableView.reloadSections`

Again it might be dependent on your requirement. In general, we don't see tableview inside a tableview cell.